# Creating models and controllers to interact with web services

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, model-view-controller, model

I'm new to asp.net MVC. I'm working with some XML web services and need to create a web application to interact with them.

The web application will consist of a table of all the tool's id and description which will populate a form with the tool's information when one of the tools on the table is clicked.

The web services are accessed normally from //localhost/dbservices/tool/id.
Each page contains XML corresponding to the specified tool's id.

I'm just confused as how to get started with this project using MVC.
I've never worked with model data that wasn't in a local database.

How would I go about assigning the XML data to my models and accessing it in the controller and then passing it to the view?

Here is some code I am trying. I made a web forms application that was similar to this in the past. Here I am trying to pass a list of all the tools to the controller. I've taken some code from that and am trying to implement it into my MVC application. I'm wondering if I am on the right path here. Also included is my model view and controller for tool.

```
  public ActionResult Component()
  {
     string rt;
     WebRequest request = 
     WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/DbService/Tool");
     WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
     Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
     StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
     rt = reader.ReadToEnd();
     XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
     xmldoc.LoadXml(rt);
     XmlNodeList nodeList = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Tool");

     List<Tool> ToolIdList = new List<Tool>();
     Tool[] toolArray = new Tool[3];
     List<string> toolList = new List<string>();
     foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
     {
        toolList.Add(node.InnerText);
     }
     foreach (Tool tool in ToolIdList)
     {
        foreach (var toolId in toolList)
        {
           tool.ToolId = toolId;

        }
     }

     return View(ToolIdList);
  }
```

Tool Model:

```
 public class Tool
 {
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string ToolId { get; set; }
 public string Adapter { get; set; }
 public int TNumber { get; set; }
 public List<string> ComponentList { get; set; }
 public List<string> AccessoryList { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Tool>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ToolId)
}
```

Comment: So where you would have got the values from the database, you now get them from the web service.

Comment: I've added some code in my question. Does this seem like the right path to take?

Comment: Looks OK. But you should dispose of the stream and the streamreader, best way is to wrap them in `using` statements.

Comment: actually. In my view, nothing is being displayed. I'm not sure why as I think my code is mainly correct. Do you see any obvious errors that would cause nothing to be returned in my view?

Comment: Looks to me like `ToolIdList` is never populated.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest the XmlSerializer class to you. It has a deserialize method that will basically unpack your xml to an object (which is what is giving you a hard time in your code)

Deserializer documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73(v=vs.110).aspx

Example of setup and use:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/487571/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part-2

Also, extract your web call outside of your controller to a helper method . Your web call isn't re-usable as is now and you are going to be forced to write duplicate code if you need to call the service from any other controller method across your site.